# gfortran runtime error:cannot change STATUS parameter in Open statement

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I have a open statement in my program using `status=replace` The code sample below:

```
do i=1,n
  open(11,file="energy.dat",status="replace")
  open(12,file="trajectory.dat",status="replace")
  do j=1,m
    ...
    write(11,*)energy
    write(12,*) x,y
    ...
  enddo
  close(11)
  close(12)
enddo
```

It's ok to compile. When I run this, It give a runtime error:

> Fortran runtime error: Cannot change STATUS parameter in OPEN
>   statement

[image]

What is the problems here?

Comment: Have you previously opened those files before reaching the loop?  Please create a complete example so we can rule such things out (see [mcve]).  And also show the exact and complete output from the compiler (unless it really does have that spelling mistake - in which case someone should report it to the vendor).

Comment: @francescalus 1.No I haven't opened those files before the loop. 2. the exact error is like what I post here. nothing else.

Comment: Please do not upload pictures for error messages. They **must** be entered as text to be searchable. I am sure the dialog box for uploading the picture told you so, did you read it? If you don't know how to copy text from a Windows terminal, just search the interwebz https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/copy-to-the-clipboard-from-the-windows-command-prompt/

Comment: And I second the request for the complete code. We must know whether the file was already opened before in the program.

Comment: @VladimirF I cant paste the whole code here,and I am sure the two files was only opened in the loop.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I am dumping the variables `energy, x, y` to diagnose.

Comment: That does not matter, we need a [mcve]. And the error message **must**, I repeat, it **MUST** be entered as text, not as a picture. Please do change it. It is not optional.

Answer (score 2):

I know the problem, it is because I actually didn't `close(11)` properly after the `j` loop. So the open statement can't change the status.